# Download Base64 Qr Code in Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filesystems, expo, qr-code

I am creating expo react native app where i generate Qr Code. After it generate when user click save button i want to save qr code in phone. I try this code but but it give Expected URL scheme **'http'** or **'https'** but was **'data'**

**Below is my code**

```
downloadFile(){
    const uri = "data:image/pdf;base64"+base64_qr
    let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "QRCode.pdf";
    FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
        this.saveFile(uri);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
}

saveFile = async (fileUri) => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status === "granted") {
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri)
        await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false)
    }
}
```

Can someone helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   async downloadFile(){
      try {
          let filePath = await Print.printToFileAsync({
              html:' <div style = "margin-top: 40%; margin-left: 30%;"><h2 style = "margin-left: 50px; font-size: 45px;">LetMeIn</h2>'
                  +'<img src="' + base64_qr +'"'
                  + 'alt="Red dot" style = "margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" />'
                  + '<h2 style = "margin-top: 50px;">Scan the QR Code to check in</h2>'
                  + '</div>',
              width : 612,
              height : 792,
          });

          const pdfName = `${filePath.uri.slice(
              0,
              filePath.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1
          )}QRCode.pdf`

          await FileSystem.moveAsync({
              from: filePath.uri,
              to: pdfName,
          })

          console.log('PDF Generated', pdfName);
          this.saveFile(pdfName);

      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Visit [how to use expo file system to save a QR code in gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217663/how-to-use-expo-file-system-to-save-a-qr-code-in-gallery/74219954#74219954) for complete code of creating a QR Generator app in react native and Expo. You can Generate a QR Code from text input, convert it into an image and then share it or save it to your phone's storage.