# how to use expo file system to save a QR code in gallery

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on a react native project using expo. It consists of creating a QR code (which I have done), converting QR code to an image and then saving it to gallery.

I want to convert my QR code to an Image and then save it into my gallery or share it. In the code given below, at compilation time it gives an error.

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.setState')

Here I am pasting my QrGenerator.js file :
`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    Box, Heading, Center, Button,
    NativeBaseProvider, Text, Input, FormControl, Stack
} from "native-base";
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';

export default function QrGenerator({ navigation }) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState("name");
    const [productQRref, setProductQRref] = useState('');


    const handleChange = (text) => {
        setInput(text);
    }

    const image_source = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80'; // I want to convert this image into base64

    const share = () => {
        var self = this;
        self.setState({ loading: true })
        FileSystem.downloadAsync(
            image_source,
            FileSystem.documentDirectory + '.png'
        )
            .then(({ uri }) => {
                console.log(self.state.base64Code);
                FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
                    uri,
                    self.state.base64Code,
                    { 'encoding': FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 }
                )
                    .then(() => {
                        this.setState({ loading: false })
                        Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
                    })

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <Center mt="20">

                <Heading color="#0891b2">VCard Generator</Heading>

                <Box marginTop="5">

                    <QRCode value={input + '\n'} size={170} />

                </Box>
            </Center>

            <Box mt="5" width="90%" margin="auto" >

                <Text fontSize="md">Fill below parameters to generate your QR Code</Text>

                <FormControl>
                    <Stack>
                        <FormControl.Label >Text</FormControl.Label>
                        <Input placeholder='Enter Text' onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)} />
                    </Stack>
                </FormControl>

                <Button mt="5" onPress={share}>Download QR</Button>
                {/* <Text>{productQRref}</Text> */}
            </Box>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    )
}
```

`
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Anikit Raj did you get a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using expo file system. There are some changes because I am using Expo to create my app.

Below is the code for generating a QR Code , getting the reference from QR Code and changing it to svg and enabling share option on button clicked.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {Box, Heading, Center, Button, NativeBaseProvider, Text, Input, FormControl, Stack} from "native-base";
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system;
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';

export default function QrGenerator({ navigation }) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState("name");
    const [state, setState] = useState();
    let svg = useRef(null);
    let dataUrl = '';

    const handleChange = (text) => {
        setInput(text);
    }

    const getDataURL = () => {
        svg?.toDataURL(callback);
    };

    function callback(dataURL) {
        dataUrl = dataURL;
    }

    const image_source = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80';

    const share = () => {
        getDataURL();
        setState({ loading: true })
        FileSystem.downloadAsync(
            image_source,
            FileSystem.documentDirectory + '.png'
        )
            .then(({ uri }) => {
                console.log(dataUrl);
                FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
                    uri,
                    dataUrl,
                    { 'encoding': FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 }
                )
                    .then(() => {
                        setState({ loading: false })
                        Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
                    })

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <Center mt="20">

                <Heading color="#0891b2">VCard Generator</Heading>

                <Box marginTop="5">

                    <QRCode value={input + '\n'} size={170} getRef={(c) => (svg = c)} backgroundColor="white" color="black" />

                </Box>
            </Center>

            <Box mt="5" width="90%" margin="auto" >

                <Text fontSize="md">Fill below parameters to generate your QR Code</Text>

                <FormControl>
                    <Stack>
                        <FormControl.Label >Text</FormControl.Label>
                        <Input placeholder='Enter Text' onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)} />
                    </Stack>
                </FormControl>

                <Button mt="5" onPress={share}>Share QR</Button>
            </Box>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    )
}
```